# Order of operations and rounding for microcontrollers

Tags: c, arm, math, compiler

I was working on a project where I read a value from a 16-bit ADC and scaled it to obtain the reading of a sensor. For example:

```
uint16_t reading = sampleSensor();
uint16_t temperature = reading/0xFFFF*2.5*1000*2;
```

Where the ADC has a full scale value of 2.5 volts with output code 0xFFFF and my sensor has a response of 2 °C/mV output.

Obviously when this code runs, it doesn't work. The value of `temperature` jumps from 0 to 5000 when `reading` increases from 65534 to 65535.

So I rewrote it and evaluated the scaling expression to a single multiplication:

```
uint16_t reading = sampleSensor();
uint16_t temperature = reading*0.076295;
```

This works as expected and `temperature` increases by 1 °C when `reading` has increased by 14 bits. I like writing out the full expression so I can keep track of the ADC bit count, VFS, and sensor gain, and I assumed the compiler would evaluate this arithmetic expression, before performing the operation on the `reading` variable.

Is this an issue with a compiler (GNU ARM v7.2.1) setting, or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding?

Comment: The specific order of operations is not defined for the first statement as they all have the same ordering rules. The division by 0xFFFF could be the first operation and that would be legal.

Comment: reading/0xFFFF seems to be an integer division. Did you try: uint16_t temperature = (reading*2.5*1000*2)/0xFFFF; and maybe there is no need for parentheses.

Comment: Nothing to do with microcontrollers, it's just a C language problem.

Comment: This is fairly basic stuff. Unrelated to the bug, you shouldn't use floating point unless you have an actual FPU.

Comment: @Lundin: Why? If the compiler has a good-enough soft FP implementation, why should you reinvent the wheel? It sounds like premature optimization to avoid FP by default.

Comment: @MSalters Because most low-end embedded systems have _outright horrible_ soft FP. Most 32 bitter compilers might handle it decently but _lots_ of people reading posts here still use legacy 8 or 16 bitters.

Comment: If performance was an issue, it can even make sense to optimize the `/0xFFFF` part. That's an integer division and almost equal to `>>16`. The difference would be in or after the 16th bit, and you're rounding `temperature` to 16 bits anyway.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is not a compiler issue: doing the division first here is the legal behaviour, as division and multiplication have equal precedence and are evaluated left-to-right. (Also, when in doubt: use parentheses; there's no penalty.)

You are working with integers, so `reading / 0xFFFF` will always evaluate to 0 if `reading` is a `uint16_t`, unless `reading == 0xFFFF`.

If you want to use integers only, force the multiplications to be done first by using something like `(reading * 10000) / 0xFFFF` and make sure both the intermediate result (`reading * 10000`) and the result fit in the available bits (use `uint32_t` for such calculations).

Note that on MCUs without an FPU floating-point arithmetic is very slow and best avoided.

Comment: Not any bracket. Parentheses only.

Comment: @Peter-Mortensen: Language glitch; thanks; fixed.

Comment: _"doing the division first here is legal behaviour"_ -- or indeed the only way it may be compiled?

Comment: @ilkkachu: Indeed, edited.

Comment: You need to be careful that the multiplication doesn't overflow if you are using `uint16_t`

Comment: @PeterMortensen "brackets" there would be normal in British English instead of "parentheses" (in both mathematical and programming usage)

Comment: @Chris-H: Yes, language glitch. I suppose "parentheses" is less ambiguous, but, with tongue firmly in cheek: I am Dutch, and not all that well-versed in the patois spoken in the colonies.

Comment: @user7761803: I thought I had already indicated that, but I made it more explicit.

Comment: @ocrdu Thanks for the answer. The MCU I am using is an EFR32MG22 (Arm M33 with FPU) so I assume floating point arithmetic is fast.

Comment: Regarding overflow, one dirty detail is that `0xFFFF` is of type `unsigned int` which is 32 bits on a EFR32. (Unlike 0x7FFF which is `int`... because... C language...) So it will type promote the `uint16_t` implicitly. Which is subtle and dangerous. For those who aren't certain of how all [implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules) work in C, then it is good advise to only ever use `uint32_t` when coding 32 bit embedded systems and tag all integer constants with postfix `u`.

Comment: @Lundin, hmm, if `0xffff` fits in an `int`, then isn't the type of that constant an `int`? And then, since the `uint16_t` is probably an `unsigned short`, it gets promoted to `int`. Probably doesn't matter though, since the 32-bit `int` can't overflow with those constant factors.

Answer (score 14):

This is a fundamental C issue: you need to be extremely clear whether you're doing integer or floating-point arithmetic.

```
 uint16_t temperature = reading*0.076295;
```

That promotes "reading" to "float", because 0.076295 is a float literal, then does the multiplication.

```
uint16_t temperature = reading/0xFFFF*2.5*1000*2;
```

The first two elements are integers, so the division is done as integer. *Then* it's promoted to float.

```
uint16_t temperature = ((float)reading)/0xFFFF*2.5*1000*2;
uint16_t temperature = reading/((float)0xFFFF)*2.5*1000*2;
```

Either of those two ought to work, and makes the arithmetic explicit.

Note that on some microcontroller architectures, the floating point arithmetic may take much longer than the integer arithmetic. Try it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6n77K8): you'll see that it's implemented as function calls rather than CPU instructions.

Comment: shouldn't even need the second set of parens, `(float) reading / 0xFFFF * 2.5 * 1000 * 2;` should be fine (and more readable, IMO).

Comment: Even in your "improved" form, the operation will require a single-precision division and three double-precision multiplies.  If the code were to compute `reading * (float)(2.5*1000.0*2.0/65535.0)`, all of those computations would be simplified to one single-precision multiply.

Comment: "That promotes "reading" to "float","  Actually it promotes it to `double`, because `0.076295` is a double literal.

Answer (score 6):

In C, operators at the same level of precedence are evaluated in left-to-right order. So, in your first equation the division is done first.

As a general rule in integer arithmetic you should try to perform the multiplications first, while avoiding overflow. Do the division last.

But you have other concerns here. If you are using a 16-bit ADC then you should use `uint32_t` types for the computations. If you use a `uint16_t` and then divide by `0xFFFF` you will never get anything other than `0x0001` or `0x0000`. Also, you should be dividing by \$2^{16}\$ rather than \$2^{16}-1\$, which can be accomplished by a right shift of 16 bits if multiplication is expensive on your processor.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `uint32_t` to avoid overflow

Comment: A typical 16-bit ADC will represent a full-scale voltage with a reading of 0xFFFF.

Comment: @supercat: What ADC? The ones we sourced saturate around 0xFE00 though it would return 0xFFFF for overvoltage.

Comment: @Joshua A unipolar 16-bit ADC should provide a maximum output value of 0xFFFF. It sounds like you had an 8-bit ADC but your driver returned the output value left-justified in a 16-bit word.

Comment: @supercat True. But the value of an LSB is \$V_{REF}/2^N\$ where \$N\$ is the number of bits. So the maximum digital output value does not correspond exactly to \$V_{REF}\$ but to \$V_{REF}\times (2^N-1)/2^N\$....assuming that's the issue you were trying to address with your comment.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: Actually not. Everything from 0x00 through 0xFE00 was observable. I wrote the driver by hand reading the bits off the pin, so ...

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have pointed out what you're doing wrong with precedence. But you do still have problems with using floating-point if your micro doesn't have floating-point support.  The compiler will sort it out, but it'll be very slow.

For dividing by a constant value where you're scaling one fixed range to another fixed range, you can get a reasonable approximation by using selective bit-shifting.  Right-shifting divides the value by powers of 2, and you can use this to get something close to the division you need.  This will not be perfectly linear, but it will be much faster than using software floating-point, and if you have noise on your analogue signal and ADC measurement then the linearity of this scaling may not be an issue.

For your example, you can scale 0 to 65535 down to 0 to 4999 with the following:

```
uint16_t temperature = (reading >> 4) + (reading >> 6) + (reading >> 13) + (reading >> 15) - (reading >> 9);
```

With regular divides, this would be

```
uint16_t temperature = (reading / 16) + (reading / 64) + (reading / 8192) + (reading / 32768) - (reading / 512);
```

but of course you don't want to use actual divides!  Compilers sometimes aren't smart enough to work out that dividing by a power-of-2 constant can be done with a bitshift, and if you rely on it with compilers that are smart enough, you can get tripped up when you change micros/compilers.

Checking this with Excel over the 0 to 65535 range, it is linear to 3 lsbs over the full range.

The general method is to start with a right-shift for the maximum input value (65535) which puts you in the right ballpark for the desired output (4999), and then progressively add (or subtract) more shifted terms until you get to the right total.  Because you are correcting the difference using the upper bits of the value, it remains relatively linear.

This is basically a riff on the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).  Surprisingly though, I've never seen it published anywhere before I came up with the idea.  I first used it for the 10-bit ADCs which were/are common on PIC and Atmel microcontrollers, to normalise an ADC measurement of 0 to 1023 into a convenient hundredths-of-volts scaling of 0 to 1000 with less than 0.5 bit linearity error over the range.  It was published in *Everyday Practical Electronics* in the early 2000s (and won me an LCR meter as the best submission for that edition! :)  I would link to the article, but EPE's archives are a bit spotty and I can't easily find it now.

Comment: Order of evaluation doesn't really apply here. You seem to be mixing up the terms. See [What is the difference between operator precedence and order of evaluation?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278172)

Comment: "Compilers often aren't smart enough to work out that dividing by a power-of-2 constant can be done with a bitshift"  20 years ago maybe... can you name a modern one which can't do that optimization?

Comment: @Lundin It depends on what you call "modern".  For microcontrollers, their compiler support isn't necessarily improved substantially over the years.  My last encounter with a little Atmel, about 6 years ago, the compiler certainly couldn't.  I'll change that line to say "sometimes" though, because you're right that more modern compilers should be able to, but equally it's still more reliable not to make that assumption.

Comment: @Lundin Fair point that I should have said "precedence" instead of "order of evaluation".  I was assuming the OP was a newbie and they might not have met the word before, so I thought that might be clearer.  But yes, I should make that correct.

Comment: If you speak of AVR then it's some 30 years old legacy architecture. Overall, we ran out of arguments for using 8 bit MCUs well over 10 years ago. Sure, there's still tons of old crap out there, I maintain numerous products with old MCUs myself. But when writing code for a modern Cortex M, you shouldn't need to do such trivial optimizations (such as swapping x*2 with x<<1 etc) manually.

Answer (score 2):

[edited in response to comments]

To add to the other excellent answers, here is something I have found extremely helpful to clarify both order-of-ops *and* type conversion, avoid many of the integer math related bugs on the CERT list (mentioned here as an example, not for compliance purposes), and write significantly more reliable integer math code in C, compared to use of more complex expressions, parenthesized or otherwise:

*1 arithmetic operation per line of code.*

In addition, and this is even more controversial, I would prefer operators like += , -= , *=  etc, rather than the infix forms ("a+b" etc). It will avoid many *but not all* gotcha's and draw attention the intermediate types.

Please don't take the above as an authoritative claim, rather it is my personal approach for making it easier to follow the effects of type conversion, overflows, and special cases, when writing integer math code.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all. You should probably have made this a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: fair enough, but the OP seems to already know that the source of the problem is type conversion, so this is intended to be more of a useful practice to bring it into the light in the future.

Comment: What is the *"CERT list"*?

Comment: How will one arithmetic operation per line of code prevent the underflow (division by 0xFFFF)?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen -- CERT list, integer section is [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87151979) // re: division by 0xFFFF - one operation per line allows clear thinking when going through code looking for bugs

Comment: This does not necessarily make it easier to follow the calculations.  Maths uses parentheses to make order-of-operations unambiguous in written equations, and this is something that everyone is already familiar with.  There is no reason not to use the same principle when coding.  Perhaps it could be a stepping stone for beginners to think about what they're doing, but I'd be very reluctant to recommend it generally.  That CERT list is basically a catalogue of pathologically bad coding practises, and if you're ever hitting those then you have bigger problems than just your integer arithmetic.

Comment: "That CERT list is basically a catalogue of pathologically bad coding practises" - yes, that is literally the purpose of that list. And odds are, whatever device you typed that comment on, runs a code base which at some point *since its public release* discovered and fixed a bug in every single category that is listed.

Comment: This isn't very helpful advise, because the compound assignment operators like `x+=y;` are equivalent to `x = x + y;` and there may be implicit promotions inside those expanded expressions and you can't cast the operands to avoid such. So it is hard to achieve MISRA or CERT compliance when using compound assignment. Overall I would recommend to use MISRA-C over CERT-C, since the former is much more suited for embedded systems.

Comment: @Lundin - +1 for the MISRA recommendation. I mentioned CERT not for strict compliance, but simply because it is a well known list of C programming pitfalls. Why can't you cast x += (foo_t)y ?  Anyway, the general concept is to minimize the number of operations per line, so that when you're working through something checking for overflows and special cases (-32768/-1 and so forth), to see whether it is okay to use native arithmetic operators vs safety-wrapped functions, this becomes error prone. Well worth the extra lines. I started doing this as a habit about 5 years ago and never looked back.

Comment: PS- IMO  x += y ; z = x;  is easier to manage than z = (x+y) -- assume all 3 are diff types -- obv. this is trivial, it is when combined with more stuff that it matters // also the point is to avoid resorting to casts

Comment: Consider something like `uint8_t x,y; ... x -= y;`. Here both `x` and `y` are promoted to signed `int` by implicit integer promotion. An unsigned operation can't underflow but a signed one can. It's then undefined behavior and the compiler is free to generate some nonsense code and might do so during optimization. The bug fix is to cast both operands to a large unsigned type that isn't implicitly promoted. Now how do you do that with compound assignment? You can't. With simple assignment you could simply do `x = (uint32_t)x - (uint32_t)y;`.

Comment: you would use an intermediate value with the type you want:   u32_z = x; u32_z -= y; x = u32_z  .. also you would check that x>y

Comment: but I take your point about casts, thanks for raising that issue.

Comment: It's practical experience from working with coding standards like the mentioned ones. Neither MISRA nor CERT bans compound assignment, but in practice you tend to always end up rewriting such expressions manually whenever the tools find implicit promotions.

Comment: @Lundin: The Standard would allow an implementation with 32-bit `int` that's given `uint16_t q = 15; for (int i=0; i<n; i++) q*=q;` to assume that `n` won't exceed 1, but even gcc doesn't do such a thing.

Comment: @supercat -- wrong thread?

Comment: @PeteW: My point was that the Standard would suggest that `uint16_t` would promote to `signed int` to perform the multiply as part of the compound assignment, but even compilers where such promotions can cause wacky behavior don't treat consequent `signed int` overflows nonsensically in this case.

Comment: Well it's hard to come up with good examples since bugs related to integer promotion are almost always subtle and rather unique. Regardless, it's a sound idea to never allow implicit promotions to be present in your code, particularly not in embedded systems where lots of bitwise operations are common.

Answer (score 0):

#### Magic Numbers

This is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Define it once at the top of your code, outside any individual function, so that it just gets calculated or assigned **once**, and include a comment (syntax will vary by language, and I haven't programmed in C in *many* years, but the concept will work in any language):

```
# temperature = reading/0xFFFF*2.5*1000*2
SENSOR_TEMP_FACTOR = 0.076295;
```

or calculate it in that statement:

```
float SENSOR_TEMP_FACTOR = 2.5 * 1000 * 2 / 0xffff;
```

You can (*should*) include more comments, explaining *why* 0xFFFF, 2.5, 1000 and 2.

Then use this constant everywhere:

```
uint16_t reading = sampleSensor() * SENSOR_TEMP_FACTOR
```

If you change to a different sensor type, you will only have to change *one line* in your code, instead of potentially several different lines for different readings.

Comment: um, no, manually writing it out is not good. Consider what happens if someone has to change one of the intermediate factors. They'll have to change it in two places, which is just a recipe for either the value or the comment getting not changed. Also, why bother deciding on the rounding when the compiler can do it for you. `float SENSOR_TEMP_FACTOR = 2.5 * 1000 * 2 / 0xffff;`

Comment: @ilkkachu I actually considered writing out both methods. Thank you - I'll edit.

Comment: Better still, give *all* those magic numbers names, and then the calculation line could look something like `float SENSOR_TEMP_FACTOR = TEMP_SENSOR_MAX_VOLTS * MV_PER_V * TEMP_SENSOR_DEGREES_C_PER_MV / TEMP_SENSOR_MAX_TICKS`

Comment: Also note that `2.5` is a `double` constant. Probably doesn't matter in this case, but it will on some FPUs. Make it a habit of _always_ using `2.5f` when using `float`.

Comment: @Lundin The specific syntax will vary for C vs. Python, etc. My concern here is the *concept* of calculate or assign *once* and then use the result as a constant everywhere.

Comment: Just a detail - the advise about avoiding magic numbers is sound. But well, this question is about C. I wouldn't use pythons for embedded systems or as scarfs - in either case I might end up strangled... :)